# hide api key for a Github page

Tags: ajax, github, authorization, github-pages

I have a github page for my organization where I would like to call data from a 3rd party api where I need an auth token. Can I publish this github page without having the auth token displayed on the public repo?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In short, no. If your GitHub repo is public, all its assets are public. You can make the repo private and it will still publish on GitHub Pages if named with the `username.github.io` convention or if it has a `gh-pages` branch. While that's an option, that's not necessarily the right thing to do.

If your key is in your GitHub Pages repo, it sounds like it's used for client-side API calls in JavaScript. If so, your auth token is publicly visible whether it's in your public repo or sent in your client-side files to the browser. This is usually fine. The third-party API might have generated the auth token based on your website's domain, and restrict calls using that token to pages originating on your domain. Otherwise, they might require the auth token only for logging requests and monitoring usage.

If the auth token is truly meant to be private, then you may need to write private server-side code to call the third-party API. Your GitHub Pages site could then hit your service for the data it needs. I've had to do that before where the web API had security concerns, but I still needed to retrieve non-sensitive data from the client-side.

Answer (score 18):

In short yes, you can store the auth token in an **environment variable** and use **gitignore** on the **.env** file to hide the auth token in the public repo. Refresh the auth token on the client-side API then push changes to the public repo and redeploy your updates to the **gh-pages** branch. I've provided an example of this process below.

**NOTE**

If you committed a password or API key, change it! If you committed a key, generate a new one. Reference general best practices on [GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository).

If using **React** for your app, **SKIP steps 1 and 2** as **React** already comes pre installed with custom environment variables. Reference [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

**The full explanation can be found below:**

**1.** Install **dotenv** dependency in application root directory (will be using **Node.js** for this example) Reference [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), run command:

`npm install dotenv`

**2.** Add code below to import statements in **index.js** file.

`require('dotenv').config();`

**3.** Create **.env** file in root directory of app and add auth token as variable. Note when using **React** you must prepend variable name with `REACT_APP_`

`AUTH_TOKEN=987asc8iks0lenv7`

**4.** Use **console.log()** on **process.env** to check if the variable was stored correctly.

`console.log(process.env.AUTH_TOKEN);`

**5.** Update all references to auth token in application code.

`OLD VARIABLE: const auth_token = '987asc8iks0lenv7';`

`NEW VARIABLE: const auth_token = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN;`

**6.** Create and add **.gitignore** file to the root directory of application and add code below to have **git** ignore the **.env** file where the auth token is stored.

`.env`

**7.** Add, commit and push updates to application **master** branch on GitHub.

**8.** To deploy or redeploy updates to **gh-pages** branch. Use command below.

`npm run deploy`

Comment: Wouldn't your `AUTH_TOKEN` still be exposed as part of the request, which can be viewed from the Network tab in browser dev tools? This doesn't seem to address the fundamental concern with making the call directly from client-side code.

Comment: No, your `AUTH_TOKEN` will not be exposed as it will be stored in an environment variable. You're adding the .env file to your .gitignore file as well which hides it from your commit history.

Comment: It won't be exposed in the public repository (which is what the question asks, sure), but as Will Klein mentioned in his answer, it'll still be accessible and viewable in the browser. That's still an issue worth noting.

Answer (score 6):

The answer of Ashen won't work for this use case. Secrets configured through Github are only available to Github Actions ([see documentation](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets)), and because of that - in practice - mostly to CI/CD-like applications. Not for e.g. client-side API calls.

Answer (score 2):

The [GitHub Actions](https://developer.github.com/actions/) should facilitate your need.

> You can add secrets using the visual workflow editor or the repository settings. Once you create a secret, GitHub encrypts the value immediately and you can no longer view or edit the value. Anyone with write access to a repository can create and use secrets in that repository.

However, the GitHub Actions is currently available in public beta and therefore should be avoided for high-value workflows and content during this beta period.