# Can you Hide your API Key on GH-Pages?

Tags: github-pages

GitHub Pages requires your repository to be public. However, I have an `.env` variable that is using an API key to call my CMS, and I would not like that API key to be shown.

Does GitHub or GitHub Pages have a way to do that?

I have used a `.gitignore`, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939713/hide-api-key-for-a-github-page?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hide api key for a Github page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939713/hide-api-key-for-a-github-page)